# Detect come from background for Facebook Instant Games

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

I'm building an idle game and wondering if there's anyway to know when a player returns to the game from background (without relaunching the game)? After browsing through APIs, I only found the onPause event but not resuming.

Thank you!
Mars

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any solution through the official Facebook API. But if you are using Cocos Creator then you can listen to cc.game events.